# Python microsoft graph api

Tags: python, api, loops, graph

I am using microsoft graph api to pull my emails in python and return them as a json object. There is a limitation that it only returns 12 emails. The code is:

```
def get_calendar_events(token):
  graph_client = OAuth2Session(token=token)

  # Configure query parameters to
  # modify the results
  query_params = {
    #'$select': 'subject,organizer,start,end,location',
    #'$orderby': 'createdDateTime DESC'
    '$select': 'sender, subject', 
    '$skip': 0,
    '$count': 'true'
  }

  # Send GET to /me/events
  events = graph_client.get('{0}/me/messages'.format(graph_url), params=query_params)
  events = events.json()
  # Return the JSON result
  return events
```

The response I get are twelve emails with subject and sender, and total count of my email. 
Now I want iterate over emails changing the skip in query_params to get the next 12. Any method of how to iterate it using loops or recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking something along the lines of this:

```
def get_calendar_events(token):
  graph_client = OAuth2Session(token=token)

  # Configure query parameters to
  # modify the results
  json_list = []
  ct = 0
  while True:
      query_params = {
        #'$select': 'subject,organizer,start,end,location',
        #'$orderby': 'createdDateTime DESC'
        '$select': 'sender, subject', 
        '$skip': ct,
        '$count': 'true'
      }

      # Send GET to /me/events
      events = graph_client.get('{0}/me/messages'.format(graph_url), params=query_params)
      events = events.json()
      json_list.append(events)
      ct += 12
  # Return the JSON result
  return json_list
```

May require some tweaking but essentially you're adding 12 to the offset each time as long as it doesn't return an error. Then it appends the json to a list and returns that.

If you know how many emails you have, you could also batch it that way.